# Twilio Stream. How to recognize a worker and customer speech differently?

Tags: stream, twilio

As a developer, I want to recognize a worker and customer speech differently via Twilio Stream. The problem is all speech comes to the server with `track='inbound'` attribute. I see no difference in a request.

Comment: How are you setting up the stream?

Comment: @philnash, updating a call with twiml verb (stream). actually, not sure it makes sense how I setup a stream. I still can't find an option to recognize a speech

Comment: When you set up a stream all you get is the audio data, you need to use that audio stream however you want, including sending it off to a speech recognition service.

Comment: @philnash, yeah, it makes sense but how can I determine who is exactly speaking? a customer or a task router worker?

Comment: I think you need to set the `track` attribute to `both_tracks` to get both: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream#attributes-track

Comment: I tried it, but the both audio identified as `inbound`

Comment: That sounds like a bug then. I'd report that to [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) along with Call SIDs of affected calls.